# Remove Shapes With Specific Name form Stage in EaselJS

Tags: createjs, easeljs

If I have shapes being added to the stage in a loop, like this:

```
fooShape = new createjs.Shape().set({name:"newShapes"});
```

What is the easiest way to have a function that removes all shapes with the "newShapes" name?

I've tried things like `stage.removeChild(fooShape[i]);` but I'll get "not defined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [removeChild method](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#method_removeChild) only display objects as parameters. To remove all children with a specific name, you have to loop through the children, and remove any that match the criteria:

```
for (var i=container.numChildren-1; i>=0; i--) {
    var child = container.getChildAt(i)
    if (child.name == "newShapes") {
        container.removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

Note that this sample loops through the children in reverse, since removing an item will cause the indexes to change during the loop.

Hope that helps.